# Did Yahoo stop adjusting historical mutual fund prices for dividends?

Tags: mutual-funds, yahoo-finance

When or why did Yahoo Finance stop adjusting historical mutual fund prices for dividends and capital gains? For example, FBALX and FSUTX both declared dividends on 4/6/2018, and FSUTX declared a capital gain as well. However, Yahoo's historical prices show the adjusted prices to be the same as the closing prices for both funds for the trailing period. Going backwards in time, the adjusted price departed from the closing price only on and before 12/6/17 for FBALX, the time of the last previous distribution. Thus, the previously posted adjusted prices are still there, but they are not updated to reflect the new distribution.

Is this a new policy, an oversight, a bug, or what?

Comment: Do you mean that a price that _used_ to be adjusted is now shown _not_ adjusted (i.e. they appear to have rewritten history) or that they (appear to) have stopped adjusting prices as current prices become historic prices? It might help if you can [edit] in links/examples to the phenomenon you are seeing.

Comment: Yahoo still presents Close and Adjusted Close data.  Yahoo is also notorious for occasional bad data moments.  Are you sure that the fund went ex-div and there was no data adjustment?  Perhaps you can provide some symbols?

Comment: I updated my previous post to more clearly explain the issue. In answer to Bob Baerker, these Fidelity funds did go ex-dividend on the same date, but as of yesterday─two weeks later─Yahoo took no notice. In response to TripleHound, the prices that used to be adjusted are still adjusted, but they have stopped adjusting prices to reflect new distributions.

Comment: I took a look at a few Fidelity Select funds that had significant quarterly distributions last week.  You are correct.  Yahoo has not updated the adjusted close.  I can't tell you whether this is new policy or your typical Yahoo data screw up.  If the adjustment of the close shows up in the next few days/weeks then you'll know that it's fixed when they get around to it.  If not, it's new policy.  I suspect it's the former.